# How to compare a CSV Host_Name field to a Hashtable Host_Name field and then merge the data into an Out-File in text format

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Need to take my `$sw` CSV file and use `foreach` to compare that against a hash translation table `$swtranslation`, Key field, then output matches including the hash table's values that match into a text file.

Problem I have is it runs the search for a few minutes and returns the sw_names.txt output file with nothing in it.  It should have well over 1074+ matches.  My guess is my syntax or something is not right.

See code for what I have going so far.

```
# This is the CSV file listing all the network switches I need to run against the translation table.
$sw = Import-Csv .\AllDeviceForExport.csv -Header Host_Name, IP_Address 

# Compile the switch translation table for processing and convert to hash //
$swtranslation = @{};

Import-Csv .\sw_translation.csv -Header Host_Name, DataSpace_ID | % {
    $swhash[$_.Host_Name] = $_.DataSpace_ID
} 

# Run the Switch listing $sw against the translation table $swtranslation 
# matching the DataSpace_ID and merging DataSpace_ID and Host name and 
# all other switch fields together in output //

foreach ($key in $swhash.Keys) {
    $sw | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$outputhash[$swhash.Keys($_.Host_Name).Value]}},* |
        Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $null } |
        Foreach { $_ -replace '--' } |
        Out-File ./sw_names.txt -Force
}
```

Expected results:

```
Host_Name            DataSpace_ID
ABC-123-3750-SW1          1
DEF-234-2950-SW1          5
DEF-234-2950-SW2          5
GHI-567-4510-SW1          6
GHI-567-4510-SW2          6
```

Comment: You create a hash table `$swtranslation` but never use it. It's unclear where `$sw` stems from. The `ForEach($key in $swhash.keys){` has no closing bracket `}`. You pipe the Select-Object through the Where to a ForEach with a -replace what stringifies any possible objects.

Comment: LotPings - I added the comments for the $sw which is the source of switches CSV file we run against the hash table.   Could you using my code, put an example here as to what it should look like?  I will take a look now and make these modifications and see what I get.

Comment: I see what I did with creating the Hash table and then not using it.   I am making some modifications and will see if this fixes it.  If anyone has an example of this process described, would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It doesn't look like `$swtranslation` is being used at all... It looks like `$swhash` is doing more than `$swtranslation`.. Can you supply sample contents of both CSV files (with fake data) and elaborate more on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: `$outputhash` is undefined in your code, and your `foreach` loop doesn't use the loop variable at all, not to mention that your output file is replaced with every iteration. Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are after.

You have two csv files without headers,

```
.\AllDeviceForExport.csv -Header Host_Name, IP_Address 
.\sw_translation.csv     -Header Host_Name, DataSpace_ID
```

Usually one builds a hash table from one file and iterates the other to check if there are matching properties or not.

What your code tries to do is building the hash table, iterate the keys of it and then (very inefficiently) on each key search the whole other file thwarting the whole idea.

Not knowing which files `Host_Name` property should be checked I suggest a different approach:

Use `Compare-Object`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\15\SO_57515952.ps1

# simulate $swtrans = Import-Csv .\sw_translation.csv -Header Host_Name, DataSpace_ID 
$swtrans = @"
ABC-123-3750-SW1,1
DEF-234-2950-SW1,5
DEF-234-2950-SW2,5
GHI-567-4510-SW1,6
GHI-567-4510-SW2,6
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Host_Name, DataSpace_ID 

# simulate $sw = Import-Csv .\AllDeviceForExport.csv -Header Host_Name, IP_Address
$sw = @"
DEF-234-2950-SW1,192.168.234.1
DEF-234-2950-SW2,192.168.234.2
GHI-567-4510-SW1,192.168.567.1
GHI-567-4510-SW2,192.168.567.2
GHI-567-4510-SW3,192.168.567.3
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv  -Header Host_Name, IP_Address

Compare-Object -Ref $swtrans -Diff $sw -Property Host_Name -PassThru -IncludeEqual
```

This yields:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\15\SO_57515952.ps1

Host_Name        DataSpace_ID SideIndicator
---------        ------------ -------------
DEF-234-2950-SW1 5            ==
DEF-234-2950-SW2 5            ==
GHI-567-4510-SW1 6            ==
GHI-567-4510-SW2 6            ==
GHI-567-4510-SW3              =>
ABC-123-3750-SW1 1            <=
```

The `SideIndicator` Property can be used to specify which lines to output and itself suppressed.

Comment: Thank you LotPings, your answer resolved the issue, I put my modified code at the bottom of my original posting.  I apologize for the mess of code in my original post, great job deciphering it!  Results are perfect.  I went straight with compare-object vs Hash and that did it.